# Vinyl record limited to 700 meaning?

Tags: vinyl, record, vinyl-pressing

[image]
What does it mean when a vinyl record says "Limited to 700"?

Answer (score 4):

It's a limited release, they only pressed 700 copies.  It's intended to make the copies more valuable (similar to limited releases of prints for visual artists).

According to [this site](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Ministry-Amerikkkant/release/12246825), it looks like there were other releases of the album, but only 700 of the gray-and-black swirl limited edition vinyl.

[This site](https://slyvinyl.com/) specializes in limited releases, you can compare some of the others they have listed there.